# Multiple forms in forms.py

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

This is a Django project.

**forms.py**

```
class BigForm(forms.Form):
    template = forms.CharField(label='Template', widget=forms.Select(choices=CHOICES))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('template'),
            Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-success')
    )


class DateForm(forms.Form):
    start_date = forms.CharField(label='Start date')
    end_date = forms.CharField(label='End date')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('start_date', css_class='form-control'),
            Field('end_date', css_class='form-control')
        )
```

**views.py**

```
def myForm(request):
    main_form = BigForm()
    date_form = DateForm()
    return render(request, 'polls/main.html', {'main_form': main_form, 'date_form': date_form})
```

Is there something wrong with this? I keep getting
KeyError: "Key 'end_date' not found in 'BigForm'. Choices are: template."

I just want two separate form classes (for two separate forms)

Comment: You are using crisply forms

Comment: Yes I am using crispy forms

Comment: Does it work? Approve answer

Comment: No it doesn't, I still see the error message. But never mind, I will try and ask a different question. Maybe my code/form design is wrong.

Comment: You should show the entire traceback, because it's not clear on which line this error is produced. I don't believe this error can occur on any of the lines of code you show here.

Answer (score 1):

You have not declared `end_date` as a field within `BigForm`. It exists in `DateForm`.

Comment: Why would I have to declare end_date in BigForm? I just want to use it in DateForm

Comment: You have indeed declared `end_date` in `DateForm`, but according to the error that you posted in your question, you are getting a `KeyError` looking for `end_date` in `BigForm`. Post the entire traceback of your error message so we can see exactly where the problem is.